# How Can I read line in txt file and then display only certain characters in TextBox VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to search for, then display a specific line in a .ino file then display that in a TextBox.
First I write many lines to a text file and once the vb.net program is closed I would like to then read from the same file. This is so if I have 50 textboxes I dont have remember what order everthing goes in. I can read from the file and make 1 change. So far I can write everything to file I need. So next step is to read from it. Any advice here is much appreciated.

So far everything is just created with normal objectwriter and so on

When I create the file I am only inserting the textbox info amongst other text below is an example. Idealy read the charater '49' and then display what i wrote in text box. 49 is what I would search for and then display nuts when i read from the file

The code is pretty staright forward to write to a text file

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub BtnWrite_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnWrite.Click
        Dim filepath As String = "C:\temp\test.txt"
        If System.IO.File.Exists(filepath) = True Then
            Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(filepath)
            objWriter.Write("#include <Arduino.h>" & vbCrLf)
700 line inbetween
            objWriter.Close()
            MessageBox.Show("File Create")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("File Does Not Exist")
        End If
    End Sub
```

The text file saves as

```
if(nuts_state){strip.setPixelColor(49, red);strip.show();delay(0);}
else{strip.setPixelColor(0, off);strip.show();delay(0);}
```

[image]

Comment: You've used the VB.NET tag but shown C# code. Which is it?

Comment: @ Andrew The little code snippet you see there is for arduino. I am using VB to creat a program that will creat an arduino .ino file which is robbly why it looks like C#

Comment: @Steve. I have icluded a little but there of what is working but its 700 odd lines so wont pop it alll there the second snippet is the bit in the .in file I am trying to read from

Comment: File.ReadAllLines and String.Contains() should help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about storing the data in a Dictionary allowing you to use key-value pairs:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dictionary.Add("1", "Some value 1");
dictionary.Add("2", "Something");
```

Then using a JSON serialization library, like Json.Net, write the dictionary out to a file:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictionary);
File.WriteAllText("File.Txt", json);
```

Then read it back in using the JSON library:

```
Dictionary<string, string> previousDictionary = 
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string> (File.ReadAllText("File.txt"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not need to any of this. Usersavforms allows you to enter values for the textboxes then recall them

```
Sub SaveFormState(ByVal SourceForm As Form)
```